# What is meant by the phrase "inclusion of categories induces an equivalence of categories"?

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I am looking through Hovey's "Model categories" and the above mentioned phrase comes up several times. Here is a couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

Does this phrase have a strict meaning? Is there a definition of "a functor $F$ inducing a functor $G$"? I really hope that it is not just a very fuzzy way to say "well, we can somehow in an undefined way construct functor $G$ by using functor $F$".

Thank you.

Comment: The equivalence is induced by localizing along the weak equivalences in the construction of the homotopy category.

Comment: I am assuming that Ho is a functor on the category of categories. If this is true, then applying the Ho functor to the inclusion functor gives a functor which is an equivalence of categories.

Comment: @MarkSaving not quite, but pretty close. The development in the text makes it clear how to interpet this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Localization $HoC = C[W^{-1}]$ together with the canonical map $C \to HoC$ has a universal property: any morphism $C \to D$ which takes weak equivalences to isomorphisms factors through $C \to HoC.$ This way, the map $C_{cf} \to C \to HoC$ factors through $HoC_{cf}.$